# cron job didn't run with oracle path and with path bash script didn't run

Tags: bash, oracle, shell, cron

**I have wrote a shell script in which the error is while i exported oracle path the corn job run successfully upto EOF and it is showing bash command not found like as cut,ls..etc 
**
*The main problem is without exporting oracle path shell script run successfully and corn job didn't executed*

```
#!/bin/bash
function execute_sql(){
export ORACLE_HOME=/Oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.2/db_1
export SET PATH3=/Oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.2/db_1/bin:. 
sqlplus system@xe/oracle123 << EOF > /usr/home/cron.log
@/usr/home/usr/date_expired.sql > /usr/home/usr/date_EXPIRED.txt
EOF
return
exit
}
execute_sql

function processing(){
SourceFile="/usr/home/usr/date_EXPIRED.txt"

#if [ -f "$SourceFile" ]; then

    cut -c-3 /usr/home/usr/date_EXPIRED.txt  |sort |uniq 
>/usr/home/usr/seq-TD_EXP.txt
    file=`cat /usr/home/usr/seq-TD_EXP.txt`
    j=_TDA_EXP
    for i in $file
    do
    awk -F "|" '{if (substr($file,1,3)=="'$i'" ) print $2;}' 
/usr/home/usr/date_EXPIRED.txt > /usr/home/usr/usr_seq/$i$j$today.txt
    done
#fi
rm -r /usr/home/usr/seq-TD_EXP.txt
return
}
processing
exit
```

**The main requirement is i want to run corn job for that script and manipulate it**

Comment: Please paste your script [there](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to fix problems.

Comment: There is no error in script , only bugs that i am getting is in corn job while executing with export path of oracle sql file is not generated and while i use export path , bash script is not working , That is the main problem i got @Cyrus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your problem description very well, but I think the problem may be with this command:

```
export SET PATH3=/Oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.2/db_1/bin:.
```

I think what you want is:

```
export PATH="/Oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0.2/db_1/bin:$PATH"
```

Explanation: "`SET`" doesn't belong there, `PATH3` isn't a relevant variable, and you should keep the old `PATH` (which adding `$PATH` to the new value does). Also, adding "`.`" to the `PATH` is not always safe.

I'd also recommend cleaning up the `awk` command:

```
awk -F "|" -v "i=$i" '{if (substr($file,1,3)==i ) print $2;}'
```

Explanation: `-v "i=$i"` copies the shell variable `i` to an awk variable with the same name; you can then use this directly in the `awk` program.